# EF left joins table everytime I include child

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've read some topics on how to include all properties in EF Core.
I have something like this:

```
_dbcontext.Transaction
.Include(x => x.Enterprise).ThenInclude(x => x.Manager)
.Include(x => x.Enterprise).ThenInclude(x=> x.Address)
.Include(x => x.Enterprise).ThenInclude(x=> x.Example)
...
```

Each time include Enterprice, entityframework creates a new left join row. Resulting in something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) x.Id, x.OtherColumnNames...
FROM Transaction as x
LEFT JOIN Enterprise AS e1 on x.EnterpriseId = e1.Id
LEFT JOIN Enterprise AS e2 on x.EnterpriseId = e2.Id
LEFT JOIN Manager AS m1 on e2.ManagerId = m1.Id
LEFT JOIN Enterprise AS e3 on x.EnterpriseId = e3.Id
LEFT JOIN Address AS a1 on e3.AddressId= a1.Id
LEFT JOIN Enterprise AS e4 on x.EnterpriseId = e4.Id
LEFT JOIN Example AS e1 on e4.ExampleId= e1.Id
...
```

Any suggestions on how I can make ef only left join my Enterprise table once? Because this isn't a pretty way to make the database calls and is slows down the entire query.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` duplicating is a known EF Core issue. Unfortunately it wasn't fixed in EF Core 1.1. Accordingly to [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4900), the issue is assigned to `2.0.0` milestone without any estimated release date.